# Laravel Composer Require Messed Up everything

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, composer-php

I have kinda messed up my project and need some help asap. So I have made a dashboard for my company completely on Laravel. It was working great until I used composer require to update a package. But instead of updating that single package, it updated all and even removed some of them. Because of that, the site went down. And it also started showing multiple errors.

Is there a way to restore the composer file somehow or did I mess up big time? Any help is appreciated!!

I tried to use the composer.lock file to get back to the older version of the packages but I had the very old version of it because the latest version was not committed..even that didn't work..at first, at least I was getting errors now it just shows 'Http error 500'.

Comment: While I feel for your loss, this is a lesson to keep multiple backups of projects in the futureso you don't suffer such losses.

Comment: I want to add that you might also need to overthink other development practices. How is it possible that the latest version was not committed, how did it get onto production?

Comment: I am one man army. And not being a native software developer I am not used to these practices. I just made this app as a temporary solution and it surprisingly worked well and it is what we are using.

Comment: Why not deploy the last working version of your application again? Sounds like you need to implement a CI pipeline that checks your application before merging such changes. Nevertheless: without sharing any code or error message, it's impossible to provide help

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions you could try out.

1. If you have versioned your project you could.

Git to revert back to a previous commit where your project was working correctly. To do this, run "git log" to identify the commit you want to revert to, and then run "git checkout [commit hash]" to switch to that commit

2. use your IDE history

Using your IDE history you can target the specific files and reset your composer.json, composer.lock back to the previous working version